# Getting error in 2.0 and above OS when adding calendar event

Tags: android, calendar

I am using below code. Its working fine for android 1.6 but its throwing below error for android 2.0 and above version. Please let me know the solution for it.

**Error:**

01-24 16:55:28.315: ERROR/ActivityThread(208): Failed to find provider info for calendar
01-24 16:55:28.315: ERROR/error(208): Unknown URL content://calendar/events

**To read Event:**

```
private void readContent(String uriString) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String columnNames[] = cursor.getColumnNames();
            String value = "";
            String colNamesString = "";
            do {
                value = "";

                for (String colName : columnNames) {
                    value += colName + " = ";
                    value += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(colName))
                    + " ||";
                }

                Log.e("INFO : ", value);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }
```

**To Add event**

```
private void addEvent(){
    try {
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", "1");
        event.put("title", "tet event");
        event.put("description", "hello this is testing of event");
        event.put("eventLocation", "Ahmedabad");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long date = c.getTimeInMillis();
        event.put("dtstart", date);
        event.put("dtend", date);
        event.put("allDay", 1);
        event.put("eventStatus", 1);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
        Log.e("uri", url.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should know, that **on new Android versions the URI for Calendar content provider has changed**, now you should use content://com.android.calendar/

Yes it´s a crap :(

So **if you was using content://calendar/ ,to get successful,now you should use content://com.android.calendar/**

If you want to maintain a compatibility across all Android versions of your apps, you will need to handle the Old URI along with the New URI, you can do something like this:

```
Uri calendarUri;
Uri eventUri;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7 )
{
  //the old way
  calendarUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"); 
  eventUri    = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
}
else
{
 //the new way
 calendarUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
 eventUri    = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
}
```

But, lets play a bit xDDD

```
function Uri getCalendarURI(eventUri boolean){
Uri calendarURI = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7 )
    {
         calendarURI = (eventUri)?Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"):Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    }
    else
        {
        calendarURI = (eventUri)?Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"): Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
    } 
 return calendarURI; 
}
```

Or in one line :

```
function Uri getCalendarUri(eventUri boolean){
    return  (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7 )?((eventUri)?Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"):Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars")):(calendarURI = (eventUri)?Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"): Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"));
}
```

Note : android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is available since SDK_INT = 4 i mean Android 1.6,for prior version android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK more info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION

Comment: Hello yeradis, My sdk version is 8, but still i am getting 'Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar' error even after using the URI "content://com.android.calendar/calendars" . Please help me in resolving this error.  Thanks, Swathi

Comment: i get the same problem in my app. i solved it by answer thanks.

Comment: @Swathi EP some custom roms(ex: HTC with Sense) have changes the default content provider uri, but that was in the past , dont know right know if there is the same problem, also you should take care on multiple accounts option